# Has this family of Diophantine equations ever been studied?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, perfect-powers

This might be a trivial question, so, if it is, I will delete it as soon as I get an answer. I try to come up with conjectures once in a while. After all, the sleep of reason produces monsters (Francisco Goya, 1799). Recently, I came up with one (perhaps someone already did), and it is this:
Will the family of equations
$$a^n=k_1^{n-1}+k_2^{n-2}+\ldots+k_{n-2}^2,$$
always have at least one solution for each $n > 0$ and $k_i>0$?

Just so I'm even more clear, when $n = 8$, we have the following:
$$a^8=k_1^7+k_2^6+k_3^5+k_4^4+k_5^3+k_6^2.$$
I wrote a computer program and the cases $n = 3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15$ have at least one solution. I left out the cases $n = 1,2$ because one can obtain solutions by hand. So, has this ever been studied? I don't even know what to call this family of equations, so I can't just perform a Google search.

Comment: Let $a>1$, and let $k_1=k_2=\dots=k_6=1$  Set $$k_7=a^8-k_1^7-k_2^6-\cdots-k_6^2$$  The first power at the end makes it trivial.

Comment: Seems like you just rewrote the equation to obtain the first power.

Comment: Yes, absolutely.  As I said, having a first power makes it trivial.

Comment: I'll get rid of it and see what happens, then.

Comment: That makes it a much more interesting question, I think.  There is a list of "sums of powers" conjectures and theorems in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sums_of_powers) and this one doesn't appear, so it may be new.  On the other hand, the list is surely not exhaustive, and I'm no expert (or I wouldn't be looking in Wikipedia.)

Comment: I appreciate the heads-up. I will dig deeper into the list and follow the links. Who knows where I'll end up.

Comment: What should the equation be for $n=1$? The right hand side seems to be an empty sum then, so there are no solutions if $a\neq0$.

Comment: Also, do you allow the $k_i$ to be negative? Do you allow them to be $0$? And are you asking about the existence of solutions for *each* $a$ and each $n$, or for *some* $a$ for each $n$?

Comment: As noted above, the first power at the end makes the problem trivial. But without it, it is clear that for $n=3$ you will find no solution to $a^3=k_1^2$ whenever $a$ is not a perfect square.

Comment: On the other hand, if $a$ is also a free variable, then we can always take $a=1$ and $k_1=1$ and $k_i=0$ for $i>1$ to get
$$1^n=1^{n-1}+0^{n-2}+\ldots+0^2.$$
But if you require the $k_i$ to all be nonzero, the problem seems hard to solve explictly for all $n$.

Comment: When $n=1$, we have $1^1=q^0$ for any natural number $q$. No, negative $k<sub>i</sub>$ are not allowed and they also can't be $0$. Good catch. I'll add this new information to the question. Finally, I'm interested in the existence of solutions for some $a$ for each $n$.

Comment: $16=2^4=-- ^3+--^2$?

Comment: That may have no solution(s), but I could always give $15^4$ = $36^3$ + $63^2$, meaning that $n=4$ has at least one solution. We are interested in $n$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For $n=3$ we have the solution $1^2=1^3$, and for $n=4$ and $n=5$ we have the solutions
\begin{array}{rrrrr}
28^2+&8^3\hphantom{+}&=&6^4\\
2^2+&3^3+&1^4=&2^5
\end{array}
Now suppose $n\geq5$ and that $k_2,k_3,\ldots,k_{n-1}$ are positive integers such that
$$k_2^2+k_3^3+\ldots+k_{n-1}^{n-1}=2^n.$$
Then setting $k_n=2^n$ we have
$$k_2^2+k_3^3+\ldots+k_{n-1}^{n-1}+k_n^n=2^n+2^n=2^{n+1},$$
which shows that we have a solution for $n+1$ as well. Hence by induction there exist solutions for all $n\geq3$.

Comment: Yes, that would seem about right.